# processing only for first outer for-each loop

Tags: php

I have a for-each loop, within for-each loop

similar to:

```
 foreach ($arr1 as $v1) {
     foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
          [ processing goes here ]
     }
 }
```

Now I need to processing only for first outer loop, not for every other time.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$clone = $arr1;   // clone for future use
foreach (array_shift($clone) as $v2) {   // loop for first element of clone of $arr1, if starting index is known, $arr1[0] can be used instead of array_shift($clone)
          [ processing goes here ]
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $v1) {
     foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
          [ processing goes here ]
     }
break;
}
```

Or you might do, simply:

```
foreach ($arr1[0] as $v2) {
    [ processing goes here ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstTime = true;
foreach ($arr1 as $v1) {
    if($firstTime) {
        $firstTime = false;
        foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
            [ processing goes here ]
        }
    }
}
```